# ValueObject in C# getting the error The entity type 'SkillLevel' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, configuration, domain-driven-design

This is my `SkillLevel` valueobject class, that it should be used in `EmployeeSkillType` join table:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace sales.Domain.Common.ValueObjects
{
    public record SkillLevel 
    {
        List<Skill> Skill; 
        List<Level> Level; 

        private SkillLevel() { }

        public SkillLevel(List<Skill> skill, List<Level> level) 
        {
            Skill = skill;
            Level = level;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where I'm using it:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

using Pluralize.NET;
using sales.Domain.Common.BaseEntities;
using sales.Domain.Entities.Payroll;

namespace sales.Infrastructure.Data.Configs.Payroll
{
    internal class EmployeeSkillTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<EmployeeSkillType>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EmployeeSkillType> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable(new Pluralizer().Pluralize(nameof(EmployeeSkillType)));
            builder.HasKey(ii => new { ii.EmployeeGuid, ii.SkillTypeGuid });
            builder.HasOne(e => e.Employee)
                .WithMany(es => es.EmployeeSkillType);
            builder.HasOne(st => st.SkillType)
                .WithMany(es => es.EmployeeSkillType);
            builder.HasMany(sl => sl.SKillLevels).WithOne();

            builder.Navigation(e => e.Employee).AutoInclude();
            builder.Navigation(st => st.SkillType).AutoInclude();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error

> The entity type 'SkillLevel' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types,

I didn't try very much - I changed it to jsonb but I got another error

Comment: Just a guess, but try `OwnsOne` instead of `HasOne` for `SKillLevels`. This Might require serialization of collections in this object since by default as far as I remember it will store the data in the same table as parrent. Error is because there is no key in your value object (nor should it be)

Comment: Do you configure `SkillLevel` as the middle table in your database? Have you  tried to follow the error message to add an primary key in this model or just configure `HasNoKey` in `OnModelCreating` method?